# Homestead/Vagrant `* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code`

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am getting the below error while running the `vagrant up` command  within `~/Homestead`  -

> The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code`

Here's the output from my terminal after running `vagrant up` within `~/Homestead`

```
Josephs-MBP:Homestead Joey$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
homestead-7: Box Provider: virtualbox
homestead-7: Box Version: >= 0.4.0
==> homestead-7: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
homestead-7: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
==> homestead-7: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v1.0.1) for provider: virtualbox
homestead-7: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/1.0.1/providers/virtualbox.box
==> homestead-7: Successfully added box laravel/homestead' (v1.0.1) for 'virtualbox'!
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
```

How do I fix my issue with the host path?

Your truly,

Total Newb

Answer (score 1):

You have a synced folder configured from your Vagrantfile but this folder does not exists.

Create the folder `~/Code` on your mac and run again (you can run `mkdir -pv ~/Code`)

Comment: Create a folder called Code in my Home directory and then run vagrant up?

Comment: Here's my most recent error:


`==> homestead-7: Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: Unit php7.0-fpm.service not found.
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.`